# Celery not using all concurrent slots

Tags: python, celery, distributed-computing

I have a Celery cluster made up of machines with 8-core processors.  Each machine has one worker that is set to a concurrency factor of 8 (-c8).

I often see nodes with a lot of reserved tasks, but only one or two are running simultaneously.  My tasks are often long-running with a lot of compute and I/O.

Any ideas as to why this is happening, and what I can do to increase the number of tasks simultaneously running?  Does celery throttle the number of active tasks based on system load? I looked through the documentation but came up short.

Comment: Are your tasks running subprocesses? Because Celery will count them in the concurrency as well.

Comment: I think that is probably the case!  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [banana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801037/banana), I think I found the answer.

Some of my tasks were spawning subprocesses, which Celery counts in its concurrency.